# ListView in NestedScrollView doesn't show properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, listview, scrollview

I've created a *NestedScrollView* and put a *LinearLayout* containing a ListView. Its *ArrayAdapter* works fine. But when I set the height of the *ListView* to wrap-content, it only shows the first item (row).

The *NestedScrollView* works fine. I've tried it with some *TextView*s.

I set its hight to 100dp, so the *ListView* showed more items ,but not all of them.

What should I do to see all of the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue happened to me also. I replaced **listview** with **recyclerview** and set the height to wrap-content. Problem solved !!